# Injected AppDbContex but not all data is remembered in subsequent calls

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I hope I explain this properly... I have a .NET Core application where I register the AppDbContext in the StartUp's ConfigureServices method like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase());
```

I'm using a CommandHandler to save an Asset. The command handler code is as follows:

```
public class SaveAssetCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SaveAssetCommandHandler.SaveAssetCommand>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public SaveAssetCommandHandler(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Handle(SaveAssetCommand command)
    {
        var asset = command.Id != null
            ? _context.Set<Asset>()
                .Single(o => o.Id == command.Id)
            : new Asset();

        var assetType = _context.Set<AssetType>().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == command.AssetTypeId);

        asset.Id = command.Id;
        asset.SerialNumber = command.SerialNumber;
        asset.PartNumber = command.PartNumber;
        asset.AssetType = assetType;

        if (command.Id == null)
            _context.Set<Asset>().Add(asset);
    }

    public class SaveAssetCommand
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public int AssetTypeId { get; set; }
        public AssetType AssetType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now here, the AppDbContext get injected, and sets the model's properties (notice I set the asset.AssetType property with a value). Control returns to the invoker where AppDbContext also get injected, and calls SaveChanges.

When I return to the Controller, I make a call to RedirectToAction to the Index action, where I use an AssetRepository to list all my assets:

```
public class AssetRepository : IRepository<Asset>
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Asset> _Assets = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Asset>();
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public AssetRepository(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Task<Asset> GetByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Assets
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Asset> GetAll()
    {
        return _Assets.Values;
    }

    public Task<List<Asset>> ListAsync()
    {
        return _dbContext.Assets
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.ManufacturedDate)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Notice that again, I inject the AppDbContext again. But when the call to ListAsync is called my list of assets is returned but the AssetType property on one of my assets is null. It was not null when I made the call to SaveChanges.

So my question is: When AppDbContext get injected in these subsequent calls, does it remember what it holds as far as the saved objects are concerned? If yes, then why am I losing the AssetType property when listing.

Comment: Read this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/

Comment: Thanks for that interesting read Steven. I learned that my dependencies are all scoped per request which now means that my AppDbContext and my repository are per request. Therefore the same instance of each should be used. Unless the call to RedirectToAction causes a new request to my Index action. That would explain why my AssetType property would be null. Would that be the reason? Am I drawing the right conclusion?

Comment: A call to RedirectToAction DOES cause the browser to submit a new request. I also checked in the browser console and that is true. So that answers my question.